# Change session and keyboard language programmatically on Windows

Tags: winapi, session, keyboard

It it possible to change the session language and keyboard language programmatically for current user via Windows API after the user has logged on? Changing some registry settings and logging off/rebooting is not a solution for me. I know that ActivateKeyboardLayout can be used to adjust keyboard but only works for the calling process.

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the keyboard can certainly be done. Changing the session language without logging of and back cannot be done.